# How can I change the state of messages to read

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, chat

When displaying all chat messages, I try to change the status of messages (read or unread).

Entity

```php
class Message
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text",nullable=true)
     * @var string|null
     */
    public ?string $text;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid",nullable=true)
     * @var string|null
     */
    public ?string $imageId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable")
     * @var DateTimeImmutable
     */
    public DateTimeImmutable $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @var bool
     */
    public bool $received;
}
```

Controller AllMessage

```php
        $message = $this->supportMessageRepository->findAllByUserId($customerId);
        $items = array_map([$this->supportMessageMapper, 'map'], $message);
```

**Idea:**
Implementation idea: when the window opens or when the user starts typing, get the flag in front true | false and if the flag is true, change the status of messages

**Problem:**
But I do not understand how I can change the status of messages (new, not yet read) when receiving a list.

**Question:**
if every time the user calls a method to get a list of messages, the call time is saved, and if it is longer than the previous one, a function is created in entity to change the state. The question is, will this work, or will I be able to change the state of only one message this way?